# if href=url change / add class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, window.location

I'm bulding a small menu and I need the help of jQuery to add or replace a class of a menu item if a sub-menu item is currently viewed.

```
<div id="menu">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sub-page-1.html">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub-page-2.html">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub-page-3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So basically if a sub-menu item is currently viewed (`ul li ul li`) I must add a class to its parent menu item (`ul li`).

I found here on the site a similar question but does not include the sub menu part and I'm clueless about jQuery.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('ul#menuHov a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass("menuHov"); 
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What do you mean precisely with "currently viewed"? I mean: a sub-menu item is showed when the parent menu item is hovered/clicked or you create the ul with some parent item with sub-menu items and others without sub-menu items?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('li a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').parent('li').addClass("menuHov"); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry but that ads the class to the link and not to the parent `ul li`

Comment: so why post something that has nothing to do with the question ? Thanks for the help any way

Answer (score 1):

```
document).ready(function() {
   $('li a').addClass("menuHov");
 var lastVisited =  document.referrer;//it can return last url
   $('li ul li a').find('href='+lastVisited).addClass("className");  
});
```

Comment: where does your example checks that the `ul li ul li` url it's currently viewed ?????

Comment: would `.parent( [selector] )` be a better shot rather that rely on referrers (that sometimes are not set ? http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the class only to parent items with sub-menu items (one time when the page load) you can simply do:

```
$('ul li ul').parent().addClass('children-viewed');
```

If you want to add the class when the sub-menu item is **hovered** you can do:

```
$('ul li ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('viewed');
},function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('viewed');
});
```

If you want to add the class **when the sub-menu items are showed** (for example when hovering their parent's item) you can do:

```
$('ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('viewed');
    // show sub-menu items
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('viewed');
    // hide sub-menu items
});
```

If with "currently viewed" you mean something else, please explain what you mean.

PS: sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT:**

Now I understand :) .
Then you can do:

```
$('ul li ul li').each(function(){
    var rx = new RegExp($(this).children('a').attr('href')+"$");
    if(rx.test(window.location.pathname)){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("menuHov");
    }
});
```

or, if you don't like loops:

```
var curr_url = window.location.pathname;
var currently_viewed = curr_url.substr(curr_url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
$('ul li ul li a[href$="'+currently_viewed+'"]').parent().parent().parent().addClass("menuHov");
```

Comment: I meant that (from the html example) if the user click on any sub-item link (`ul li ul li`) the main parent (`ul li`) class should be changed or added. - `<li><a href="page.html">Page</a>` should have a class IF the user is currently viewing any of the following pages: `            <li><a href="sub-page-1.html">Page 1</a></li>, <li><a href="sub-page-2.html">Page 2</a></li>, <li><a href="sub-page-3.html">Page 3</a></li>` I hope that makes more sense now

Comment: currently viewed = browser url

Comment: Oh, now I understand! Sorry, I misinterpreted the question! I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry but still no luck with both scripts. I think you are close or I'm missing something. There was no class added to anything after using both scripts.

Comment: Does it makes any difference if the links are `http://www.example.com/sub-page-3.html` instead of `sub-page-3.html` ?

Comment: In the second method yes, it makes a difference, as I get a substring of window.location.pathname. The first method should work, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/Polmonite/mJ6fU/2/ (you need to cick run; also the window.location.pathname in jsfiddle is '/_display/'), works.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('li a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').parent().parent().parent().addClass("yourclassname"); 
});
```

also can define #menu ul li ul li a

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#menu ul li ul li a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').parent().parent().parent().addClass("yourclassname"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` `.is()` function. Try something like that

```
$('ul li ul li').is('.open')
```

And add `.open` class identifier to the `ul li ul li` when hover by using `addClass('.open')`

More info [Here](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

IF you have example `$_GET['page']=="food"`

you will check in the url with something like this

```
function getUrlVars() {
   var vars = {};
   var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
   function(m,key,value) {
   vars[key] = value;
   });
   return vars;
}
```

Then you could have an ID on the menuitems

```
<li id="food">Food</li>
```

Then how to get the page.

```
var page = getUrlVars()["page"];

if (page){
    var currPage = $("#"+page);
    currPage.css({"background":"#eeeeee","color":"#000000"});

}else{
    console.log("No page defined!");
}
```

Comment: Over complicated, there is no `$_GET['page']=="food"` and can't be set or I don't need to set it. also I don't see on you example how the parent item would change it's class or get one, just like the question implies.

Comment: I think i missunderstod you. but i get now what you want.