# How I can make whole div Clickable with its anchor link which is present inside the div?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, wordpress

I have one box div inside that, user can easily add link for h1 tag i.e for title tag. but I require that it should apply to the whole div. The anchor tag is coming from Wordpress editor toolbar, so how can I extract that `href` and add to whole div. code is using React.

eg :

```html
<div class="box">

  <h1>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-      element">The new face of marketing</a>
  </h1>
  <p>Marketing</p>
</div>
```

I will need whatever user will add url for title it should apply to whole div and make div clickable with respect to its url.

Comment: why not wrap the div in the anchor if you want the whole thing clickable?

Comment: you can put a click event handler on div but i agree with @Pete

Answer (score 0):

**IT IS NOT Working On this Snippet** 
You can see here Codepen link [Link Open in New Tab Using Jquery](https://codepen.io/Lucifer18/pen/XWNXYzd)

You can find the URL in a tag and set it to a div for clickability using "jQuery."
When you click on ".box," you'll see the tag "a" inside. and click the link to open it in a new tab.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".box").click(function() {   
     strUrl=$(this).find("a").attr("href");       
     window.open(strUrl);return false;         
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  background:lightgreen;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <h1>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element">The new face of marketing</a>
  </h1>
  <p>Marketing</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is the following, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// find all <h1> elements that are the children of a .box element,
// and iterate over that collection using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('.box > h1').forEach(
  // using an Arrow function we pass a reference to the current
  // <h1> element into the function body:
  (heading) => {
    // we find the <a> element within the <h1>
    let anchor = heading.querySelector('a'),
      // we get a reference to the .box ancestor element:
      box = heading.closest('.box');

    // if there is an anchor (querySelector() returns null if the
    // element is not found) and the ancestor box does not match
    // the CSS selector:
    if (anchor && !box.matches('a > .box')) {
      // we insert the children of the anchor into the <h1> before the
      // anchor element itself:
      while(anchor.firstChild){
        heading.insertBefore(anchor.firstChild, anchor);
      }
      // we find the parentNode of the box element, and insert the anchor
      // before the box element:
      box.parentNode.insertBefore(anchor, box);
      // we append the box element to the anchor element:
      anchor.append(box);

      // the following may not be required, but it depends on the
      // CSS rules, so it's here in case it's required:

      // we add the class of 'box' to the anchor's classList:
      anchor.classList.add('box');
      // we remove the 'box' class for the box element:
      box.classList.remove('box');
    }
  })
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 80vw, 1200px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

main .box {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

a.box {
  border-color: orange;
}

div.box {
  border-color: lime;
}

@media screen and (width < 800px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="box">
    <h1><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element">Should be changed by the JavaScript</a></h1>
    <p>Marketing</p>
  </div>

  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element" class="box">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Should not be changed by the JavaScript</h1>
      <p>Marketing</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element" class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Should not be changed by the JavaScript</h1>
      <p>Marketing</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/obmwkt71/).

References:

- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a jQuery solution as your tag indicates, this is how I would do it.

```js
$(document).off('click.clickableBox').on('click.clickableBox', '.clickable-box', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box clickable-box" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element">

  <h1>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396721/if-href-url-change-add-class-to-parent-element">The new face of marketing</a>
  </h1>
  <p>Marketing</p>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

1. Add a `href` tag to the div you want to be clickable as well as a class `clickable-box`.
2. Define a jQuery listener to watch for any click event on a div with the class `clickable-box` and redirect the page to the url defined in the div href tag.